# Most standard way to handle communication between isolated modules in Angular 1.x

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-module

I am working on a set of enterprise style applications that share some common functionality. An example of this would be navbar functionality such as sorting/ breadcrumbs, etc. It seems pretty straight forward to allow this by creating multiple modules. [I have an example plnkr of what I am talking about](http://plnkr.co/edit/8kfT0W8cyAhH0OS7b3Kz?p=preview).

```
    var appWrap = document.getElementById('app');
    angular.element(appWrap).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(appWrap, ['plunker']);
    });
    var appWrap2 = document.getElementById('app2');
    angular.element(appWrap2).ready(function() {
      angular.bootstrap(appWrap2, ['plunker2']);
    });
```

My question is, when I need to send a value from app to app2 what would I do? Would I just create some sort of JS listener?

Comment: Could You elaborate why these have to be two separate applications, why is this solution superior over having one application with two distinct modules? If you had one app the communication problem  is easy to solve with a service, eventually via event broadcasting / emitting.

Comment: Lets keep that as an aside right now but it mainly had to do with different routing. The same routes were declared by multiple modules and this was causing issues. But again lets please keep this as an aside for now.

Comment: Well if that's the case, then because these are separate apps they don't share services and there are two different $roots so You can't use angular $events too. The only solution I see is to communicate via javascript events, probably using observer pattern.

Comment: Any how I would fire a $watch or something equivalent in the app once the change is observed? I tried doing something like https://gist.github.com/jrgleason/650c22a9a11ee03ff545 but it wouldn't fire the watch when I changed the value.

Comment: You have to specify which value, the $scope.test or the global var test value?

Comment: Well $scope.$watch when provided a string should be $scope.text. I think the problem is more how do I get the watch to fire when an item is observed from outside the module.

Comment: Remember that the $digest need to be called to make the $watch reevaluate the given value.

Comment: I tried doing the ol' angular.element(..).scope thing from the other app that seems to work as well. Will the observer pattern give me anything more than this will? I will try and put up a plnkr soon.

Comment: Well it won't give You more than this, it will just make things more decoupled. But I think it's not worth it if there will be only several events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing this a little hacky...

```
var appWrap = document.getElementById('app');
var appScope = angular.element(appWrap).scope();
console.log(appScope.property);
```

This is from the app2 module. You can also watch and other things **just make sure to $apply** since you are in a different app!